# Floating bar chart with dates as the plotted values in r

Tags: r, date, plot, bar-chart

I want to plot the *range of dates* where a particular object is "active", as shown below:

[image]

This example is taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N.W.A#Members). Here is the data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Eazy-E", "DJ Yella", "Dr. Dre",
    "Ice Cube", "Arabian Prince", "MC Ren"),
  from = as.Date(c("01/01/1986", "01/01/1986", "01/01/1986",
    "01/01/1986", "01/01/1986","02/01/1988"), "%m/%d/%Y"),
  to = as.Date(c("08/01/1991", "08/01/1991", "07/01/1991",
    "12/01/1989", "07/01/1988", "08/01/1991"),"%m/%d/%Y"))

df1
            name       from         to
1         Eazy-E 1986-01-01 1991-08-01
2       DJ Yella 1986-01-01 1991-08-01
3        Dr. Dre 1986-01-01 1991-07-01
4       Ice Cube 1986-01-01 1989-12-01
5 Arabian Prince 1986-01-01 1988-07-01
6         MC Ren 1988-02-01 1991-08-01
```

I can't figure out how to:

1. Plot the value of dates
2. Make floating bar charts

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be a bar chart per se, more of a collection of lines or rectangles. As such, this can be tackled with `lines()`, `rect()`, or even `polygon()`. I'll show the first, I hope you'll get the gist.

Your data:

```
dat <- structure(list(name = c("Eazy-E", "DJ Yella", "Dr. Dre", "Ice Cube", "Arabian Prince", "MC Ren"),
                      from = c("1986-01-01", "1986-01-01", "1986-01-01", "1986-01-01", "1986-01-01", "1988-02-01"),
                      to = c("1991-08-01", "1991-08-01", "1991-07-01", "1989-12-01", "1988-07-01", "1991-08-01")),
                 .Names = c("name", "from", "to"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
dat$from <- as.POSIXct(dat$from)
dat$to <- as.POSIXct(dat$to)
dat
##             name       from         to
## 1         Eazy-E 1986-01-01 1991-08-01
## 2       DJ Yella 1986-01-01 1991-08-01
## 3        Dr. Dre 1986-01-01 1991-07-01
## 4       Ice Cube 1986-01-01 1989-12-01
## 5 Arabian Prince 1986-01-01 1988-07-01
## 6         MC Ren 1988-02-01 1991-08-01
```

One solution:

```
par(mar=c(2,8,0,0) + 0.1)
plot(0, type='n', xlim=range(c(dat$from, dat$to)), ylim=c(1, nrow(dat)),
     main='', xlab='', ylab='', xaxt='n', yaxt='n')
years <- seq.POSIXt(min(dat$from), max(dat$to), by='1 year')
abline(v=years, lty=3, col='gray')
axis(1, at=years, labels=format(years, '%Y'))
axis(2, at=1:nrow(dat), labels=rev(dat$name), las=2)
lines(x=as.POSIXct(c(apply(dat[,c('from','to')], 1, c, NA))),
      y=rep(nrow(dat):1, each=3),
      lwd=5)
```

[image]

Increase `lwd` to get thicker lines. If you want more control over it, consider using `rect` in the same fashion.

Comment: `segments` might be more convenient than `lines` here: `segments(dat$from, rep(nrow(dat):1, 2), df$to, lwd=5, lend=1)` (using `lend=1` gives butt ends to the line, better indicating their ends). I think you might find that `seq(min(dat$from), max(dat$to), 'year')` would have worked fine with the original `Date` objects - no need to coerce to `POSIX`, I don't think.

Comment: I agree (and a rewrite would use `segments`), but this discussion goes along with "you can use `lines` or `rect` or `polygon` or `segments` or ...". I'm hoping the OP gets the idea on how to attack the basic problem, perhaps first looking at it not as a bar chart but more as a chart of bars/lines. Funny, I know, but it's perspective.

Comment: Yep, and my comments were meant more as tips for the OP. I didn't mean to suggest your post wasn't useful - relating it to a line chart (with thick lines) is sensible and leads to a y-axis coordinate system that's generally going to be easier to work with than when using `barchart`.

Comment: True. Some of these answers really could go on for pages, with multiple recipes. Like you, I think showcasing one and commenting on possible alternatives is a good way to help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach using `barchart`. First, plot a barchart where bar length is given by the end date, then plot over this with a white barchart with bar length given by start date. Use `axis.date` to add the x-axis labels.

```
par(mar=c(5, 6, 2, 2))
b <- barplot(as.numeric(df$to), horiz=TRUE, border='transparent', 
        xlim=range(c(df$from, df$to)), xaxt='n', yaxs='i',
        space=1)
barplot(as.numeric(df$from), horiz=TRUE, space=1, add=TRUE, col='white', 
        border='transparent', xaxt='n', names.arg=df$name, las=1, 
        cex.names=0.8)
axis(2, at=b[, 1], labels=FALSE, tick=FALSE)
box(bty='l')
axis.Date(1, pretty(df$from), cex.axis=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice use of `axis.date`, versus my kludgy approach in my answer. I hadn't considered double-plotting barcharts, though it looks a bit closer to the OP's referenced image. Nice.