# Create a Range Bar Chart in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, range, bar-chart

I would like to create a range bar chart in R.
I found a similar question that was posted about 4 years ago, but the answer was a bit awkward and cumbersome. It did the job, but I was hoping that a cleaner approach might be possible now. Using ggplot2 would be ideal.

[Floating bar chart with dates as the plotted values in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32662606/floating-bar-chart-with-dates-as-the-plotted-values-in-r)

If possible, I would also like to include some sort of point data, or some other way to indicate a summary statistic, like the mean or median for that particular range.

Compared to the attached picture, the Item IDs would take the place of the months given along the y-axis and the Start and End values would be represented horizontally along the x-axis.

Although the data doesn't have to be structured this way, here is a sample dataframe to make things easier:

````
structure(list(Item = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), Start = c(500, 550, 500, 
450, 400, 400, 500, 400, 300, 300, 350, 250, 300, 200, 200, 100, 
100, 50, 0, 0), End = c(550, 600, 550, 550, 700, 600, 600, 700, 
850, 600, 650, 650, 750, 900, 800, 900, 1000, 950, 900, 1000), 
    Median = c(525, 575, 525, 500, 550, 500, 550, 550, 575, 450, 
    500, 450, 525, 550, 500, 500, 550, 500, 450, 500)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(Item = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Start = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), End = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Median = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))```
````

The example picture was taken from the range bar chart entry at the "AnyChart" website.
[image]

Comment: you can use `geom_segment` to get bars like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by RAB, you can try to use `geom_segment` with your dataframe `df`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = Item, xend = Item, y = Start, yend = End), size = 5, colour = "red", alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = Item, xend = Item, y = Median-1, yend = Median+1), size = 5, colour = "black") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = as.character(ddf$Item))+
  ylab("Value")
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use `geom_crossbar`:

```r
ggplot(data = ddf, aes(x = as.factor(Item), y = Median)) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = Start, ymax = End), width = 0.5, fill = "grey") +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Item") + 
  ylab("Value")
```

[image]